# How to set Heights with Bootstrap 4 on Safari and Safari mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, safari, mobile-safari

I am building a static page with Bootstrap 4.0.0 and it works on all media and browsers except Safari and Safari mobile.
It seems they don't recognize the height of the container and don't allow scrolling. Here you can see the page and the code:
https://www.intergraf.it/test/
The body is green, "jumbotron" is blue and the container is red.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by removing the "min-vh-100" and "d-flex" classes from the jumbotron